# Cannot forward after response has been committed in Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using Servlet and Jsp for my Simple application. When I click on the Submit button it invkes the servelt and download the PDF file and Forword it to the next page. Now my question is I am using  `response.setHeader and getOutputStream` in my servlet and at the same time I am trying t forword my resquest to next page. Now it is throwing me the error saying  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed` .
Please can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Code:

```
public class Class extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
Document document = new Document();  
        ServletConfig cfg=getServletConfig();
        ServletContext application=cfg.getServletContext();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition"," attachment; filename=\"BI_Staffing.pdf\"");              
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());  

------------
---------------(My Code)
document.close();

                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("staffing-results1.jsp");
                rd.forward(request,response);   
}
}
```

Comment: You can't serve up BOTH a pdf, and html from a jsp.  You'll need to decide which one is more appropriate to give to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your "work flow". Web application is based on HTTP, which is request-response protocol. You have already responded to your request by writing to the response's outputStream. You cannot forward a respond once more. Moreover, you can open only one "output channel" - the outputStream for binary response or the writer for the textual one. Since the output stream was already opened for your PdfWriter, you cannot even obtain the writer to write a single bit.

What about displaying the staffing-results1.jsp with link to the PDF as a result of your form's submit action?